# Hint VSCode where the class definition is

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

tI have this code:

```
const Gatherer = require('../gatherer');

class MetaRobots extends Gatherer {
  /**
   * @param {{driver: !Driver}} options Run options
   …
}

module.exports = MetaRobots;
```

VSCode highlights `Driver` (inside jsdoc) because it's unable to find its definition. However, the definition of that class is in the same project:

```
class Driver {
…
}

module.exports = Driver;
```

Importing `Driver` in the `MetaRobots` file (`const Driver = require('../../driver');`) fixes the issue, but then I have an unused import.

*Can't find definition of Driver* 
[image: can't find definition of Driver]

*Can find definition of Driver, but Driver import is unused* 
[image: can find definition of Driver, but Driver import is unused]

Is there any way I can hint VSCode about definition of `Driver` w/o importing it?

[EDIT] Additional info:

- VSCode Version 1.17.2 (1.17.2)
- Some plugins like eslint, editorconfig, default ones and themes / icons
- All JS files (not TS)
- This jsconfig.json: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/jsconfig.json
- This project: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/

Comment: What version of vscode? Any additional plugins? Are those JavaScript or TypeScript type files? Do you have jsconfig/tsconfig file properly setup? Which problem reporter it is?

Comment: @jsynowiec updated my question with additional info ;) Project is OSS, so you can take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Do you have any jsdoc/jshint related plugins?

Comment: ESLint 1.3.2 and Document This 0.5.0. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's not a problem with the vscode itself but rather an issue with the TypeScript server running underneath.

Unfortunately, currently you need to import `Connection` in the `driver.js` file for IntelliSense to pick up the types properly. It's being [discussed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377) on how it should be solved. There is also [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8237) describing very similar case.

You can try experimenting with type definitions files and UMD modules but it might not work.

Comment: Boomer! Will have to wait for them to fix it. Thanks a lot!